# Do I understand this C function (qsort comparison function)?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm aiming to use [qsort from stdlib.h](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm). qsort requires a comparison function argument fulfilling this:

```
int (*compar)(const void *, const void*)
```

Am I right reading this as, "a pointer to an int-returning function f. f must take two arguments which are generic pointers"? I'm not certain of the meaning of the brackets around '*compar' - is there a name for this I can look up?

The link provides an example:

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

Would I be right reading *(int*)a as "dereferencing the value of a, after it has been cast as a pointer to an integer"?

Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *Am I right reading this as, "a pointer to an int-returning function f. f must take two arguments which are generic pointers"?*

Exactly right.

> *I'm not certain of the meaning of the brackets around `*compar`*

That's the syntax for declaring pointers to functions (which are called "function pointers"). Without the parens, it would be a function declaration

```
// Declares a function named compar. (It returns an int*.)
int *compar(const void *, const void*);

// Declares a function pointer named compar. (The func returns an int.)
int (*compar)(const void *, const void*);
```

> *Would I be right reading `*(int*)a` as "dereferencing the value of a, after it has been cast as a pointer to an integer"?*

Correct again. It gives the `int` at address `a`.

Answer (score 4):

You're in right path.

In your first example, `compar` is called a [Function pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer). The `()` are the part of the *syntax* of a function pointer.

Please, note, without the explicit `()` around `*compar`, `compar` will be treated as a *fucntion* returning an `int *`, accepting two `void` pointers.

For the second case, , for the binary subtraction operator `-`, from the `C99` standard, chapter 6.5.6, paragraph 3,

> — both operands have arithmetic type;
>
> — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible object
>   types; or
>
> — the left operand is a pointer to an object type and the right operand has integer type.
>   (Decrementing is equivalent to subtracting 1.)

and for the first point, the `arithmatic type`, from chapter 6.2.5,  paragraph 18,

> Integer and floating types are collectively called arithmetic types.

So, here, before using the pointers for subtraction, they are *casted* to `int` pointer, then dereferenced and the value(s) is(are) used as the operands for *integer* subtraction.

Comment: @ikegami not at all sir. Please consider those words as a sign of encouragement [and cheering also]. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are understanding right both of the syntax. The brackets `()` around `*compar` means that `compar` is function pointer. In absence of it the meaning will be completely different.